# getting org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! when trying to connect to heroku-postgresql Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, heroku, sessionfactory

I'm getting this error: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!`

when trying to connect to Heroku Postgres DB.

this is my hibernate configuration (i called it: `hibernateUser.cfg.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-243-213-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dess6n165jarrv</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dess6n165jarrv</property>
    <property name= "hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

   </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

enter code here

I'm implementing this as a singleton :

```
public static HibernateUserDAO getInstance(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
    {   

        instance = new HibernateUserDAO();
        if (instance == null)
        {
            userFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernateUser.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(AppUser.class).buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public void addNewUser(AppUser user) throws UserExceptionHandler, IOException 
    {   

        Session session = null; 

        int id = 0;
        try
        {
            session = userFactory.getCurrentSession();

            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();


        }catch (HibernateException e) 
        {
            if (session.getTransaction() != null) session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new HibernateException (e);
        }finally 
        {
            try 
            {session.close();} 
            catch (HibernateException e)
            {
                throw new UserExceptionHandler("Warnning!! connection did'nt close properly");
            } 
        }
        if (id != 0) 
            System.out.println("User created successfully");    

    }

enter code here
```

I'm getting the error on this line:

```
session = userFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

I think the error is in my configuration file but I cant see where is the problem is (I read a couple of examples and I copy it)

Comment: run `heroku pg:credentials:rotate` because you posted your username and password publicly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your connection parameters dynamically like this:

```
Map<String,String> jdbcUrlSettings = new HashMap<>();
String jdbcDbUrl = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");
if (null != jdbcDbUrl) {
  jdbcUrlSettings.put("hibernate.connection.url", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
}

registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
    configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
    applySettings(jdbcUrlSettings).
    build();
```

This way, they are not hard coded, and will pick up changes made by the platform. For more info see [Using the DATABASE_URL with Hibernate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-database_url-with-hibernate).

Comment: can you explain how should I init the session factory and open a session with the changes of the registry?